# ssrs count error getting 1's instead of total

Tags: reporting-services, count

Rookie mistake, 
here it is:
I got Regions and MembersID, I grouped the regions and want to count the members. When I add the count(MembersID) instead of geeting the total members, I get a bunch of 1:
RegionA    1

```
       1
       1
```

RegionB 
           1

```
       1
```

what I want:

RegionA 
         3

RegionB 2

what I did: Grouped Regions and Count[MembersID]

Please help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit tough to tell what you actually need here.

In Group Header rows, you can use aggregate functions, which will look at all rows in that current scope.

Distinct MembersID count in group: `=CountDistinct(Fields!MembersID.Value)`

Total rows in group: `=CountRows()`

In detail rows, these aggregate functions will only report on the current rows, so `=CountRows()` will only ever return one; to get the number of rows in the group you need to set the scope of the function to the group level, e.g. something like `=CountDistinct(Fields!MembersID.Value, "Group1")` or `=CountRows("Group1")`.

So based on a Dataset:

[image]

And a report which incorporates these aggregate function in the group header and detail rows:

[image]

You can get the following results:

[image]

If this is not sufficient you will need to supply your Dataset details, some sample data and how you need this sample data presented.

Comment: You're correct. My issue was that I should have hide the detail of the columns and just show total count. Thanks for you help.